# Import Error in Raspbian command when running Python script

Tags: raspbian, python

I am developing this python program to run in Raspberry Pi (Raspbian). And my program is using Kivy for UI also. What I need to do now is to make my python script executable and auto boot when startup.

I added this line of code into my first line of python file:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
```

However, I realize that if I using command to run the script, it comes out with error, stating there is no module name Kivy. For your info, the line of code is as below:

```
from kivy.app import App
```

But, if I double click on the python script, the program can run without any error and function as it is. Does anyone know what can I do to solve this error and make it autorun during boot up?

Your help is very much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `kivy` for each of the Python versions you plan to use.

```
sudo apt install python-kivy  # Python 2
sudo apt install python3-kivy # Python 3
```

It looks like you have installed `kivy` for Python 2 but not for Python 3.

Double clicking seems to be running Python 2 whereas running from the command line is honouring the `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and running Python 3.

Comment: Hi Joan, thank you very much. I just realize i missed out all the installation of those library that i called after you pointing out my mistake.
Thanks and have a nice day.